# php PDO prepare(" INSERT ..(variables ) VALUES(?,?,) produces an error need assistance

Tags: php, pdo

```
$query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO surveys (`username`,`inspected`,
    `comments`,`ip_address`,`date`,`time`)
        VALUES '(?,?,?,?,?,?)';);
$values = array ($username,$inspected,$comments,$ip_address,$date,$time);
var_dump($query);$rowCount = $query->rowCount();
$return $rowCount;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i get a null as a return since I cant get rowCount() to roduce anything

Comment: @markl17: What error do you get when you try the raw SQL query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Try changing `VALUES '(?,?,?,?,?,?)';);` to `VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";` and remove the `$` in `$return` so that it reads as `return $rowCount;` --- This `$return` is invalid. @markl17

Comment: Looks like that question "Oh my. I forgot to execute" is getting quite popular here. I wish people paid at least ANY attention to the code they write.

Comment: yes that was a major stupidity on my part still does nt change the error of the rowCount()

Comment: So, is it working for you now? @markl17

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 3 this is from phpmyadmin

Comment: Did you make the changes I suggested? @markl17 changing `VALUES '(?,?,?,?,?,?)';);` to `VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";` you still seem to have the quotes in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can base yourself on the following which I've prepared for you.

**Sidenote:** I'm not entirely sure as to why you want to use `rowCount()` for, so I left it out for now.

If you're looking to check if a record exists using `rowCount()`, let me know.

The following method works to insert data into a database, which is based on a method I use.

```
<?php
$dbname = 'xxx';
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';

try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 exit( $e->getMessage() );
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO surveys (
        username,
        inspected,
        comments,
        ip_address,
        date,
        time
        ) VALUES (
        :username, 
        :inspected, 
        :comments, 
        :ip_address, 
        :date, 
        :time)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':inspected', $_POST['inspected'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->bindParam(':ip_address', $_POST['ip_address'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':time', $_POST['time'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

// $stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username'],':inspected' => $_POST['inspected'],':comments' => $_POST['comments'], 
':ip_address' => $_POST['ip_address'],':date' => $_POST['date'],':time' => $_POST['time']));
if($stmt != false) {
    echo "success!";
} else {
    echo "an error occured saving your data!";
}
```

Comment: Maybe a `try/catch` around the guts since you've got `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` on. That last `else` block is basically unreachable anyway if an exception is thrown in `execute()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes you're right Michael, I will make an edit. EDIT: Added. Thanks Michael.